# CDNTaxReceipts extend $pdf_variables[]

Tags: extension, hooks, cdn-tax-receipts

[CDNTaxReceipts](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cdntaxreceipts) is a Tax Receipts extension for CiviCRM.
This extension is a way to generate pdf including recipient's personal data. Those Data are listed in an array `$pdf_variables` declared in [`cdntaxreceipts_generateFormattedReceipt()`](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cdntaxreceipts/-/blob/master/cdntaxreceipts.functions.inc#L261).

Is there any proper way to extend `$pdf_variables[]` ? I would like to add a `custom_field` entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look a [few lines down](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cdntaxreceipts/-/blob/master/cdntaxreceipts.functions.inc#L321) from there it calls hook_cdntaxreceipts_writeReceipt where you can do something custom. There is also hook_cdntaxreceipts_alter_receipt as described in the readme.

Comment: Thank you Demerit! Unlike this function declaration: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cdntaxreceipts/-/blob/master/cdntaxreceipts.functions.inc#L349 it is indeed possible to get $receipt as an argument of the _cdntaxreceipts_writeReceipt() function.